# Weak References and Disposable objects

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, weak-references

In C# it is possible to create weak references to objects as described here:

[WeakReference Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx)

In .net some classes also implement the IDisposable interface. Calling the Dispose method of this interface is performed to manually dispose of any managed or unmanaged resources currently being held onto. An example might be a Bitmap object or class.

If I assign an object that implements IDisposable to a weak reference, will Dispose be called if the weak reference collects the object?

Comment: What do you mean by "Weakreference" collecting its objects? it is just a weak reference, i.e. the object it is pointing to may be collected by the garbage collector. In this case all you know about the garbage collector applies...

Comment: Like Frank said the object will just be collected by the garbage collector. This in turn will trigger the finalizer, if you have such a one.
The Dispose method will never be triggered though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, the answer is indeed No.

However, a properly implemented class that implements `IDisposable` using the [IDisposable pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx) (hopefuly all .NET classes do this). Would also implement finalizer which is called when the object is garbage collected and inside the finalizer, it would call `Dispose`. So, for all proper implementations of `IDisposable`, the `Dispose` method will be called.

(Note: the counter-example by Fernando is not implementing `IDisposable` properly)

Comment: Actually, the "standard" finalizer only calls `Dispose(bool)`; `Dispose()` is not called, so any cleanup that depends on managed code (e.g., flushing underlying file streams) cannot be done.

Comment: @StephenClearly Per the pattern Dispose(bool) is called by *both* the finalizer and Dispose, with neither implementing the work.

Answer (score 6):

GC does not ever call Dispose. Dispose must be called by user code.

Comment: Your design may be better served by replacing `WeakReference` with `RefCountDisposable` from the [Rx library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No. Simple like that ;)

Answer (score 1):

No. Check this test:

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Test test = new Test();
            Console.WriteLine(test.Disposable == null);
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine(test.Disposable == null);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Test {
        private WeakReference disposable = new WeakReference(new WeakDisposable());
        public WeakDisposable Disposable {
            get { return disposable.Target as WeakDisposable; }
        }
    }

    public class WeakDisposable : IDisposable {
        ~WeakDisposable() {
            Console.WriteLine("Destructor");
        }
        public void Dispose() {
            Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
False
True
Destructor
```

As you can see, the execution never hits the `Dispose` method.

Comment: Because Dispose was never called.. If a type has *any* managed resources the it must correctly implement a finalizer (or always be properly disposed).